C++ Undefined behaviour when reinterpret cast is used
The following piece of code is undefined behavior since the lifetime of Data is not started
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
struct Data{

};
void process(char * buff){
    decltype(auto) d = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<Data *>(buff));
}
int main() {
     char buf[sizeof(Data)];
     process(buf);
}

Reading the cppreference of memmove says the following:

std::memmove may be used to implicitly create objects in the
destination buffer.

My question is if the piece of code above is changed to
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
struct Data{

};
void process(char * const buff){
    decltype(auto) d = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<Data *>(std::memmove(buff,buff,sizeof(Data))));
}
int main() {
   char buf[sizeof(Data)];
   process(buf);
}

Is the lifetime of Data implicitly started during memmove and no Undefined Behaviour ? If yes when the lifetime is ended at this example?

Note that the first example has, assuming that alignof(Data) == 1, only undefined behavior because the array is of type char. If it was of type unsigned char or std::byte, then starting the lifetime of the array would also already implicitly create objects.

std::memmove If the objects are potentially-overlapping or not TriviallyCopyable, the behavior of memmove is not specified and may be undefined.

@MarekR But neither applies in OP's example as written.

TL;DR
In general, it's still UB because you don't move an object representation from a proper object to the destination buffer.

A possible exception is if Data is of implicit-lifetime (NB it's the case for an empty struct such as in the question example).
You'll have to change your buffer declaration to unsigned char buf[sizeof(Data)] or std::byte buf[sizeof(Data)], and change process signature accordingly.
In this case, memmove is not necessary either as the bytes array creation is enough to start lifetime of such objects: see here.
Notice that, in this case, Data is still uninitialized.
Otherwise, what you can do is a placement new on buf:
int main() {
   unsigned char buf[sizeof(Data)];
   new(buf) Data; // creates a Data object at buf, be careful of alignment
   // here I'm using default constructor, other constructors can be used.
   process(buf); // don't need memmove there
}

Notice that the object representation of the new Data object is unrelated to any value previously stored in the buffer. It will depend on the constructor used.
Beside, as mentioned in the snippet, be careful of alignment. If Data is over-aligned you are still UB or you will have to use a larger buffer and std::align (or a simpler solution, see below).
Anyway this design is dangerous as, from inside process, you have no mean to be sure that a Data object actually lives at buf.

Thanks to @user17732522 comment, a way to have better guarantees on alignment would be:
alignas(Data) unsigned char buf[sizeof(Data)];


Thanks to @user17732522 comment, another option, could be std::start_lifetime_as from C++23 but you should have a valid object representation inside the buffer (getting such a representation is a different story) otherwise the object value will be unspecified.
The current wording of the question is not precise enough regarding the actual use-case to tell what would be the best solution.

Data is implicit-lifetime. So that is not a problem. "If Data is over-aligned you are still UB": It is already a problem if alignof(Data) != 1. It doesn't need to be over-aligned to cause an alignment issue. std::align and an oversized buffer is not necessary. The buffer can be aligned properly with alignas specifier.

@user17732522 I assumed that in real code Data was not an empty struct. Maybe OP should clarify.

@user17732522 AFAIK, alignas cannot be used directly to align buf, you'll have to wrap it inside a struct aligned with alignas.

If Data is not empty and the copy-constructor actually copies some members, then it will also be UB regardless of whether the memmove itself and the launder is defined because it will read an indeterminate value. @OP If your type is not as written, then it can easily become more complicated.

Why should alignas on the array itself not work? It is not a good solution in general, because the alignment will not be propagated in the type, but otherwise I do not see why it shouldn't work.

@user17732522 my bad. What would be the correct syntax: alignas(alignof(Data)) char buf[sizeof(Data)] or char buf alignas(alignof(Data)) [sizeof(Data)]?

The former and alignas(Data) is sufficient (a short-hand for alignas(alignof(Data))).

If OP has something more complicated in mind, they should also be careful that new(buf) Data will not give the new object the value according to the original bytes in the array, even if the default constructor is trivial. If they want that, they should use std::start_lifetime_as instead.

@user17732522 In C++26, that copy constructor would no longer be UB, but in C++26 you also have std::start_lifetime_as

The standard gives different properties to char and unsigned char buffers. It's unclear for me when only unsigned char (or std::byte) can be used. If someone can clarify and tell me if I need to fix my answer... (I think that the difference is in the types of array that can be used to store objects and the type of pointers that can be used to reference these objects locations).

@Artyer It would (generally) still have erroneous behavior in C++26 though, so it may still fail at runtime.

"if you have a valid object representation inside the buffer": That's not necessary. If not, the value of the object will simply be unspecified. But that's already (more or less) the case anyway because OP doesn't initialize the buffer or object at all. Of course, and that applies to the use of placement-new as well, if any subobject will have an unspecified, indeterminate or erroneous value, then the copy in the function might not behave as expected. (See discussion in previous comments.)

@Oersted an example of    this statement "except during constant evaluation, (since C++26)operations that begin lifetime of an array of type unsigned char or std::byte(since C++17), in which case such objects are created in the array,"?

for an example of implicit-lifetime object creation, you may see my answer for another post (the part starting with "second version". Or in codereview. I implicitly create a std::array into a storage.

@user17732522 About std::start_lifetime_as I agree I am other-zealous. I'm updating the answer accordingly.

I could say there are 3 potential undefined behaviors in your 2nd code block:

The behavior of memmove in case of overlapping source and
destination is not specified and may be undefined.
The destination of memmove is a pointer to const which will result in
undefined behavior.
The function's argument is now a pointer to a
constant and you are trying to cast away constness using
reinterpret_cast which is undefined behavior as well.



memmove specifically permits overlapping ranges. That's the difference to memcpy. 2. If the pointer is to a const-qualified type, then this won't compile. 3. The reinterpret_cast also won't compile if the pointer is to a const-qualified type. In fact the call to the function will already not compile. If you mean the case where the user explicitly declares the array const and then casts away const with const_cast to pass the array to the function, then that's on the caller.

